A novel where humans have to fight against huge spider-like aliens, and only veterans can vote
I read this great novel about 30 years ago. I don't remember the cover but it was a paperback.
A terrible war is fought between humans and aliens that look like spiders but are larger than humans.
An important point in the book was that only veterans of that war were allowed to vote.
There is also a movie based on the novel, but I was very, very disappointed by it since it was mostly battle scenes and all the societal aspect was almost absent.

An odd coincidence (?): the film Starship Troopers is today's (7 Nov 2024, the day you posted this question) front-page featured article on the English Wikipedia.

@Randal'Thor   Coincidence indeed. I always go to Wikipedia (often the english version) directly to the page I want, never going to the front page !

@HansOlo I just had a look at that page. Since I did not remember the title nor the author of the novel, nor the director nor the writer of the movie, I might not even have connected the movie with my memory, unless I had read the whole text till the word "Arachnids". And no mention of veteran voting, my main point. I did not know about the controversy either till it was mentioned by  rojomoke in his answer. It was my personal feeling that the movie was very inferior to the novel. I did not know that this feeling was shared by others, much less of a controversy reaching such a degree.

One point made very clearly in the book was that not only ex-soldiers got the vote (and in particular not only veterans of this particular interstellar war). Rather, you got the franchise after completing a tour of voluntary service. The most conspicuous such service is military, and the book is written from the POV of a soldier. But there is a flashback in which it is explicitly clarified that the vast majority of voters did civilian service, not military. The focus is very clearly on service, not on militarism. (And the movie got the book grotesquely wrong.)

@StephanKolassa Thank you for this important precision. I did not remember such precise details. But indeed my memory of the book was genrally very positive and the focus on servie rather than militarism is quite consistent with  this positive feeling. And the opposite focus in the movie also consistent wwith my negative feeling.

@Randal'Thor - must be pointed out that the book and the movie which accidentally was named the same way have virtually nothing in common

@StephanKolassa, do you happen to recall if it mentioned any particular sorts of civil service? I always seem to have had the impression the alternatives to military service actually presented in the book were of a rather demeaning sort, something offered for people not fit to serve even as grunts just because something has to be offered. I think there was also something about the service requiring putting oneself at risk for the benefit of others, and e.g. being a regular nurse in peace time might not cut it. (It might be time for me to re-read, but I don't have the book at hand.)

@ilkkachu: that is a very good question. Unfortunately, no, I don't have the details at hand. Someone with an ebook might be able to search for "DuBois", this being the protagonist's teacher of Moral Philosophy, in whose (flashbacked) classes most of these topics are discussed. I sadly only have the paper version, which for some strange reason does not have an index to help people look stuff like this up. Publishers should really be more user-friendly.

Was literally any attempt at finding this book done? When I googled “only veterans can vote sci-fi book” the first twenty results are about Starship Troopers.

@DanielB - They clearly knew what it was. Either they did it for the easy HNQ reputation or they were trolling.

@ilkkachu I'm scanning through the book right now, from my memories of when I read it eons ago and from my current re-reading, auxiliary services aren't about demeaning, but more about as dangerous as actual military services. The recruiting officer, Ho, told the trio that capable recruits would be placed according to their valuable skill, but if they found someone so utterly unqualified yet still insisted on applying, they'd then find a job just as dangerous as the military.

@ilkkachu  A doctor later sneers at this attitude, saying if a blind & wheelchair-bound insists on applying, they'd probably tell the recruit to count caterpillar hair by hand, but from later dialogues, it's reinforced that it's the danger that matters, such as testing dangerous tools, being a lab rat, or laboring on the frontiers.

That's got to be the classic Starship Troopers, by Robert A Heinlein.
From Wikipedia:

The story is set in a future society ruled by a human interstellar
government called the Terran Federation, dominated by a military
elite. Under the Terran Federation, only veterans of Federal Service
(including, but not limited to, military service) enjoy full
citizenship, such as the right to vote.[6] The first-person narrative
follows Juan "Johnny" Rico, a young man of Filipino descent, through
his military service in the Mobile Infantry. He progresses from
recruit to officer against the backdrop of an interstellar war between
humans and an alien species known as "Arachnids" or "Bugs".
The movie has been widely criticised for glorfying war and missing Heinlein's point.


Glad to learn I was not the only one to think that the movie missed the author's point !

@Alfred The film didn't miss the point, rather it was an attempt to deconstruct the original novel. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_(film)#Writing

@Alfred For more about the book versus film, see this answer.

@PaulJohnson - that is 100% false. The movie not only had almost nothing in common with the book; it wasn't even started with the book in mind - they just slapped the book's label on the top of unrelated movie later on, to attract more interest due to the book's popularity; without taking almost anything from the book aside from the names and some very superficial trappings.

... Even that Wiki article, among most other garbage in it about the book, admits "Davison realized the [already written] treatment bore similarities to the 1959 science fiction novel, Starship Troopers, by Robert A. Heinlein"

In any event, I didn't hear about the movie being criticized for glorifying war as compared to the book, which is actually often qualified as a war and authoritarianism pamphlet and even sometimes as a pro-fascist work. There are people who understood the movie naively as glorifying war (I was one), but I never heard of someone saying that after comparing the movie to the book.

As far as I heard, the sequence of events was like (1) Work on unrelated film starts (2) Execs notice similarities with Starship Troopers and buy the license to slap it on the film (3) Director decides to satirize the book rather than make a straight adaptation.
